# How do I join two tables with a common column that is a primary in one and not in the other?

Tags: sql-server, database

I'm pretty new to SQL and I'm trying to join two tables using a column that is a primary (and distinct) in one table but not primary (and could have multiple rows) in another. The code's below.

```
SELECT LEFT(CAST(dbo.PolicyDB.accountingmonth AS VARCHAR(4)),4) AS AccountingYear,
    SUM(dbo.PolicyDB.EarnedPremium) AS EarnedPremium,
    SUM(Loss.TotalPaidLoss) as TotalPaidLoss
FROM dbo.PolicyDB
INNER JOIN (
        SELECT SUM(dbo.ClaimDB.losspaid + dbo.ClaimDB.expensepaid - dbo.ClaimDB.recovery) as TotalPaidLoss
        FROM dbo.ClaimDB
        GROUP BY accountingmonth
        ) Loss
ON dbo.PolicyDB.policykey = dbo.ClaimDB.policykey
GROUP BY LEFT(CAST(dbo.PolicyDB.accountingmonth AS VARCHAR(4)),4)
```

Basically, I am trying to create a table that will display three columns: Accounting Year, Earned Premium (for that year), and Total Paid Loss (for that year).

I have a couple problems. First, I don't know if I'm calling Loss.TotalPaidLoss properly. I don't know of any other ways to sum multiple fields into one when its database differs from the other.

Second, the column that is joining the two, Policy Key, is a primary (and unique) key in the Policy DB but not in the Claims DB (b/c multiple claims can come from one policy). When I run this code, I get this error message:

Msg 4104, Level 16, State 1, Line 11
The multi-part identifier "dbo.ClaimDB.policykey" could not be bound.

There are probably a bunch of errors in my code, but these two are my primary questions. If you spot other errors or improvements I can make, I'm all ears. I'd appreciate any help!

Comment: The subquery that you are using in the `INNER JOIN` is a `SUM` grouped by month, but you are not selecting (or grouping by) the `policykey` column. Furthermore, the `JOIN` condition is trying to use a column from the `dbo.ClaimDB` table, instead of a column from the alias you gave to the subquery, this doesn't makes any sense

Comment: Ohhhhhhh that makes a lot of sense. I see what's going on now (I think). I was trying to join the subquery and the Policy table using a third table column from which the subquery came from as opposed to directly connecting the subquery and Policy table, correct?

Either way, I changed the join to:

    On dbo.PolicyDB.policykey = Loss.policykey

And I got results at least, even though they don't make sense. Thanks!

Comment: correct, that's what you should be doing, and the answer below has it almost right, but the join condition is wrong, it should be: `ON dbo.PolicyDB.policykey = Loss.policykey`

Comment: @lamak, yep corrected it. That was a typo. And how humiliating :-(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your second table `Loss` in the `JOIN` is actually a derived(alias) table. You should be using `dbo.PolicyDB.policykey = Loss.policykey`. But this table right now does not have PolicyKey column. It needs to be :

```
SELECT LEFT(CAST(dbo.PolicyDB.accountingmonth AS VARCHAR(4)),4) AS AccountingYear,
    SUM(dbo.PolicyDB.EarnedPremium) AS EarnedPremium,
    SUM(Loss.TotalPaidLoss) as TotalPaidLoss
FROM dbo.PolicyDB
INNER JOIN (
        SELECT SUM(losspaid + expensepaid - recovery) as TotalPaidLoss, PolicyKey
        FROM dbo.ClaimDB
        GROUP BY PolicyKey
        ) Loss
ON dbo.PolicyDB.policykey = Loss.policykey
GROUP BY LEFT(CAST(dbo.PolicyDB.accountingmonth AS VARCHAR(4)),4)
```

Also you don't need to rollup(group) the `ClaimDB` column by accounting month, I feel.

Comment: As you said, the join condition should be `dbo.PolicyDB.policykey = Loss.policykey`, but you are using the wrong one on your code

Comment: As both lamak and you said, the problem was with that joining thing. I tried to edit your post to reflect what you said because you described why it was wrong but forgot to change the code you put up.